# Why this object does not deinit when I pass the object to another view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to deinit coordinator object when I leave FeatureC view.

It does deinit when I navigate: root -> FeatureC -> back

However, it does not deinit when I navigate: root -> FeatureC -> FeatureD -> back -> back.

My expectation was when I go back to root view, coordinator object should deinit.

```
//
//  UnownedExample.swift
//  SwiftUICoordinatorExample
//
//  Created by Jason Rich Darmawan Onggo Putra on 01/08/23.
//

import SwiftUI

class Coordinator {
    let id: UUID
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct FeatureD: View {
//    unowned let coordinator: Coordinator
    
    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
//        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Feature D")
    }
}

struct FeatureCView: View {
    let coordinator: Coordinator
    
    init(coordinator: Coordinator = Coordinator()) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature C")
            
            NavigationLink {
                NavigationLazyView {
                    FeatureD(coordinator: coordinator)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Feature D")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UnownedExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    NavigationLazyView {
                        FeatureCView()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Feature C")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UnownedExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UnownedExample()
    }
}

struct NavigationLazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    
    init(_ build: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        build()
    }
}
```

2nd version

```
class FeatureDCoordinator {
    let id: UUID
    
    unowned let cCoordinator: FeatureCCoordinator
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), cCoordinator: FeatureCCoordinator = FeatureCCoordinator()) {
        self.id = id
        self.cCoordinator = cCoordinator
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct FeatureDView: View {
    let coordinator: FeatureDCoordinator
    
    init(coordinator: FeatureDCoordinator = FeatureDCoordinator()) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Feature D")
    }
}

class FeatureCCoordinator {
    let id: UUID
    
    var dCoordinator: FeatureDCoordinator?
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct FeatureCView: View {
    @State private var isFeatureDPresented = false
    
    let coordinator: FeatureCCoordinator
    
    init(coordinator: FeatureCCoordinator = FeatureCCoordinator()) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature C")
            
            Button {
                isFeatureDPresented = true
            } label: {
                Text("Feature D")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isFeatureDPresented) {
            NavigationLazyView {
                featureDView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var featureDView: some View {
        let dCoordinator = FeatureDCoordinator(cCoordinator: coordinator)
        coordinator.dCoordinator = dCoordinator
        return FeatureDView(coordinator: dCoordinator)
    }
}

struct NavigationLazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    
    init(_ build: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        build()
    }
}
```

[image: Weak or Unowned Example]

Comment: It's because you're using a strong reference to your Coordinator class.

Comment: @devdchaudhary not sure that I understand your statement. Yes, FeatureCView hold strong reference to Coordinator. But, when I leave FeatureCView it will deinit. However, once I pass coordinator to FeatureDView, it will not deinit. important: i only pass coordinator to FeatureDView.

Comment: @devdchaudhary anyway, I use UIKit and the behavior is difference. I think NavigationLink have bug.

Comment: Did you checked using VStack instead of NavigationLazyView which may be the problem.

Comment: You need to realise, that a SwiftUI view is not the same as a UIKit view. It's a means to describe how to create and how to modify the underlying views which actual render pixels. Once this _change_ has been made, the SwiftUI view value diminishes and hence your Coordinator instance as well, while the underlying view is happy to live longer until a new "SwiftUI view description" says, it no longer is there. So, the first change would be to use a _value type_ for your view variables, rather than a reference type (aka class) - or, even better, change it like suggested in the answer.

Comment: Also, what you should always keep in mind in order to find a solution to your problem is, that a _view is a function of state_. That means, it's _data_ that drives your view. You are trying to make it backward: depending on the top view, you want some data to be allocated or deallocated. Whenever you have a more complex problem, you are better of separating your logic out of the view into a model. The model computes a new state based on events sent from the view and the current state, and the view just renders it.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I think I get the idea, `separating your logic out of the view`, do you mean the `isPresented` logic? yeah I am thinking to move it to a coordinator, and coordinator will have its own view. As of right now, my goal is to understand how reference works in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

What I meant to say that this isn't the correct way of doing dependancy injection in SwiftUI views. You have to use SwiftUI ways of handling that by using `@ObservableObject` and `@StateObject`, and passing that as an `@EnvironmentObject`

So in this example when you come back to the `UnownedExample` view after exiting your view hierarchy it will automatically deallocate instance of your coordinator class.

In SwiftUI you don't actually have ownership of your class instances as it manages that internally, it automatically handles allocation and deallocation when it redraws your views.

```
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    
    let id: UUID
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
}

struct FeatureD: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var coordinator: Coordinator

    var body: some View {
        Text("Feature D")
    }
}

struct FeatureCView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature C")
            NavigationLink {
                FeatureD()
                    .environmentObject(coordinator)
            } label: {
                Text("Feature D")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UnownedExample: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    FeatureCView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Feature C")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the idea that you suggest to use .environmentObject to inject. I disagree with that. First, you have to explicitly use `@EnvironmentObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. Another the cause of my disagreement is that The example you gave does not deinit coordinator when I navigate: RootView -> FeatureCView -> FeatureDView.

Comment: @JasonRichDarmawan I my test, the Coordinator instance actually _does_ deallocate when you navigate back to the root view (`UnownedExample`). The source code apparently suggests that this is the case and expected behaviour. Did you test it?

Comment: @JasonRichDarmawan It actually _does not_ deallocate when you navigate from FeatureCView to FeatureDView. This also is expected behaviour, since FeatureCView still exists (actually, its underlying representation) and it is/may be still visible (depending on platform).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper that is unexpected. with UIKit Navigation I do not have such issue. When I leave FeatureCView, it deallocates Coordinator.